# JSF 2 - commandButton not doing action after getting rendered

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, cdi

Hey I've been struggling with this whole day, and I can't find the answer yet. So my problem is I have 2 forms in my xhtml page, the first one shows a primefaces datatable filled with data from my DB and the second one gets filled with data from the selected user to edit it. Problem is, the second form has 2 commandButtons but after I render it (via ajax call) the buttons don't seem to call the method in the action attribute.

Here is my code to get it all clearer.

This is my first form in the xhtml page

```
<h:form id="form" style="width:710px;">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="supervisor" value="#{tablaBean.modeloUsuario}"  
                             paginator="true" rows="15" paginatorPosition="bottom" selection="#{tablaBean.usuarioSel}"
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                             rendered="#{tablaBean.showAll}">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="Supervisores" />
                    </f:facet>  
                    <p:column  selectionMode="single" style="width:18px" />
                    <p:column headerText="Id" filterBy="#{supervisor.idUsuario}" filterStyle="width:35px;">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{supervisor.idUsuario}" />  
                    </p:column>   
                    <p:column headerText="Nombre" filterBy="#{supervisor.nombre}" id="nombreh">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{supervisor.nombre}" />  
                    </p:column>   
                    <p:column headerText="Ap. Paterno" filterBy="#{supervisor.apaterno}" id="apat">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{supervisor.apaterno}" />  
                    </p:column>   
                    <p:column headerText="Ap. Materno" filterBy="#{supervisor.amaterno}" id="amat">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{supervisor.amaterno}" />  
                    </p:column>   
                    <p:column headerText="Usuario" filterBy="#{supervisor.nombreUsuario}" id="user">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{supervisor.nombreUsuario}" />  
                    </p:column>    
                    <p:column headerText="Depto." filterBy="#{supervisor.departamento.nombre}" id="deptoh">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{supervisor.departamento.nombre}" />  
                    </p:column>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton id="ver" value="Ver" icon="ui-icon-search" update=":form:userData" oncomplete="user.show()" />
                        <p:commandButton id="editar" value="Editar" icon="ui-icon-pencil" update=":form,:formEdit" action="#{tablaBean.edit()}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

This is the code from my second form

```
<h:form id="formEdit">
<p:growl />
<p:fieldset legend="Editar Usuario" style="margin: auto;" rendered="#{!tablaBean.showAll}">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputText value="Id" />
        <h:outputText value="#{tablaBean.usuarioSel.idUsuario}" id="id" />
        <p:message for="id" />
        <p:outputLabel for="nombre" value="Nombre" />
        <p:inplace>
            <p:inputText value="#{tablaBean.usuarioSel.nombre}" id="nombre" required="true" />
        </p:inplace>
        <p:message for="nombre" />
        <p:outputLabel for="appat" value="Apellido Paterno" />
        <p:inplace>
            <p:inputText value="#{tablaBean.usuarioSel.apaterno}" id="appat" required="true"/> 
        </p:inplace>
        <p:message for="appat" />
        <p:outputLabel for="apmat" value="Apellido Materno" />
        <p:inplace>
            <p:inputText value="#{tablaBean.usuarioSel.amaterno}" id="apmat" required="true"/> 
        </p:inplace>
        <p:message for="apmat" />
        <p:outputLabel for="usuario" value="Usuario" />
        <p:inplace>
            <p:inputText value="#{tablaBean.usuarioSel.nombreUsuario}" id="usuario" required="true"> 
                <f:ajax render="msgUsuario" event="blur" />
                <f:validator binding="#{userNameValidator}" />
            </p:inputText>
        </p:inplace>
        <p:message for="usuario" id="msgUsuario" />
        <p:outputLabel for="depto" value="Departamento" />
        <p:inplace>
            <p:inputText value="#{tablaBean.usuarioSel.departamento.nombre}" id="depto" required="true" /> 
        </p:inplace>
        <p:message for="depto" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Guardar" icon="ui-icon-disk" action="#{tablaBean.editarUsuario()}" />
    <p:commandButton id="editar" value="Cancelar" update=":form,:formEdit" icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="#{tablaBean.edit()}" />
</p:fieldset>
```

So when I call the method "edit()" I change the showAll variable's value so it renders the second form and "hide" the first one. Problem is after I do that the command buttons in the second form do nothing. (Don't even enter the method)

Here's my bean

```
    @Named(value = "tablaBean")
    @ConversationScoped

public class TablaBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private UsuariosDao usuario;
    @Inject
    private Usuarios usuarioSel;
    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;
    private UserDataModel modeloUsuario;
    private boolean showAll;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of TablaBean
     */
    public TablaBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        start();
        modeloUsuario = new UserDataModel(usuario.findSupers());
        showAll = true;
    }

    public void start(){
        conversation.begin();
    }

    public void end(){
        conversation.end();
    }

    public Usuarios getUsuarioSel() {
        return usuarioSel;
    }

    public void setUsuarioSel(Usuarios usuarioSel) {
        this.usuarioSel = usuarioSel;
    }

    public UserDataModel getModeloUsuario() {
        return modeloUsuario;
    }

    public boolean isShowAll() {
        return showAll;
    }

    public void setShowAll(boolean showAll) {
        this.showAll = showAll;
    }

    public UsuariosDao getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(UsuariosDao usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String edit() {
        System.out.println("holis");
        showAll = !showAll;
        return "";
    }

    public String editarUsuario(){
        System.out.println("hola");
        end();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Any advice on what I might be doing wrong is appreciated, thanks in advance.

### Edit

I did a little more debugging and I found out that my managed bean is being called every time I hit the edit button in the first form, so I'm guessing the problem is my conversation bean.

### Edit 2

I changed the scope of the backing bean to Application, now it didn't get called when hitting the edit button, but the command buttons still don't work

Comment: does ajax=true need to be set on your command buttons?

Comment: no, it is the default value on the command buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error, it was something wrong in the `<f:validator binding="#{userNameValidator}" />` line, which had some error of NullPointerException in the validator (which I already fixed) but yea... I feel so stupid now! xD, I had to turn the commandButton to none ajax to actually see the error cause it was not showing in the server log. Thanks for your answers anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of PrimeFaces you're using. I've seen issues with CDI conversations being propagated correctly with PrimeFaces ajax in previous versions. Also seen issues with previous versions of Mojarra as well. Seems like this may be related.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I'm using Primefaces 3.3, Mojarra 2.1.6 and Glassfish 3.1.2